# "Select Features Using an Expression" tool is selecting wrong features

Tags: qgis, features

I'm very new to QGIS and GIS in general.

I have a shapefile of Multilines. The corresponding attribute table has a field called "Name". I want to filter the features in the table based on a condition on this field, namely, the features containing the word 'rio' as a substring.
To that end I used the "Select Features Using an Expresion" and the SQL-Like query
`"Name" like '%rio%'`. But I'm ending up with  the  result of the attached screen shot.

Why is QGIS selecting feature 65 which "Name" is "tracero_6"? And also why is QGIS isn't selecting row 58 which name is "del_rio_1"? In my opinion the former does not meets the requirements of the query while the latter does.

I have tried deselecting all the features from the layer and trying again the same query, always ending up with the same wrong selection.

[image]

Comment: Your expression looks to be correct.  Do you have any nulls in the Name field?  I ask because over the years I've found nulls sometimes mess up selections in different programs.

Comment: As has been pointed out, there is nothing obviously incorrect with your syntax, so I suspect it is a data-related issue.  Can you share a sample of your data?  I mean an actual shape file and not a screenshot of some values in a table.

Comment: Apparently nothing was wrong with the shape file. It was a matter of shooting QGIS down and starting it again. Thanks John and bixb0012 for the help